# How is this font getting loaded by this webpage?

Tags: html, css

I am looking at the web page located at [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/).  If you open this page you will see it renders all the Font Awesome's font icons.  I am having an issue getting font icons to show in IE, but they show in IE for this page, so I am trying to decipher how it is put together.  If I look at site.css and beautify.css, there is no @font-face directive anywhere.  Yet the site.css makes reference to the 'FontAwesome' in a font-family specifier.  Can someone tell me how 'FontAwesome' is getting resolved on this page?

UPDATE

Ergg, how did I miss this?  Sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's quite a few `@font-face` definitions:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'MuseoSans';
    src:url('../font/museosans_300-webfont.eot');
    src:url('../font/museosans_300-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/museosans_300-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal
}

@font-face{
    font-family:'MuseoSans';
    src:url('../font/museosans_500-webfont.eot');
    src:url('../font/museosans_500-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/museosans_500-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal
}

@font-face{
    font-family:'MuseoSlab';
    src:url('../font/museo_slab_300-webfont.eot');
    src:url('../font/museo_slab_300-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/museo_slab_300-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal
}

@font-face{
    font-family:'MuseoSlab';
    src:url('../font/museo_slab_500-webfont.eot');
    src:url('../font/museo_slab_500-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/museo_slab_500-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal
}

@font-face{
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svgz#FontAwesomeRegular') format('svg'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesomeRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If I look at site.css and beautify.css, there is no @font-face directive anywhere.

Yes, there is.

[image: Here!]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `site.css` (near the end) you will find `@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot')[...]`.

On more info how to make cross-browser `@font-face` work, see http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/